Relation between the distribution of circular particles and the distribution of their cross sections
Let us imagine that we have a three-dimensional volume filled with non-intersecting balls with some size distribution, say, $f3(r)$.
We make a mass of arbitrary cross sections of this volume by planes, and consider the circles formed by the cross section. Their size (radius) distribution is, say, $f2(r)$.
Question: how are $f2(r)$ and $f3(r)$ related? Is it possible, knowing one distribution, to predict/retrieve the other?
Perhaps you have come across some articles on these topics?

I think the hard part is dealing with the constraint that the balls actually fill space. Othewise it would be a convolution of the ball distribution with the cross section distribution $\sqrt{ r^2 -z^2}$
